# locate java source code in jdk7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, jdk

I have installed Jdk7 in Ubuntu 14.04 and it is successfully configured and I can use java libraries in code. The problem is that I am trying to locate java source 
code, but not able to find the jar file.

The below part is updated --

I run the the following command in the location `/opt/sun/jdk7`

```
find . -name *.zip
```

It didn't find anything. Given that source code could be located in the location as Julien suggested.

```
$JAVA_HOME/src.zip
```

Here is what I did while installing jdk7

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and it downloaded the package `java-7-openjdk-amd64` which seems to not have something like src.zip.

So now I got `jdk1.7.0_17` and I can find the source code in jdk1.7.0_17/src.zip

Comment: why you search for source code with a `jar` extension?

Comment: right, I should not have searched this in the files for jar extensions. let me edit my question

Answer (score 2):

The JDK sources are in `$JAVA_HOME/src.zip`.